# zend server and xampp on same computer

Tags: xampp, zend-server

hi i have installed zend and xampp server on my pc. both are working fine. 
my question is can i rum both on same PC.if yes then how can i do so.
Exactly  same problem with mysql server.
I am asking this is just for knowledge if i can do it really help me lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run them on the same machine, but I don't think it will work if you run them in the same Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, you have to remove one of these two.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can install zend server and xampp on same computer. i have both running on my windows 8 Pc. but at a time only server will run you need to switch between 2 apache depending on which server you want to run.

when you install zend server on task bar it will show 2 apache server one for zend(Apache2.2-zend) and on for xampp(Apache2.4). you can stop and start this server at any time and switch between them anytime without restarting pc.

only one will we runnning at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure both instances to run on different ports.

Apache will default to port 80 and sql to 3306. You can't run 2 web servers on the same port so you could leave one on port 80 and change the other to run on port 8080 (for example). The same for mysql, unless you just run all the databases from one of your installations and leave it on the default port.

You would then access it in the browser using http://localhost:8080/folder